# How would you use the ord function to get ord("a") as 0?

Tags: python

For example, in python, when I type in `ord("a")` it returns `97` because it refers to the ascii list. I want `ord("a")` to return zero from a string that I created such as

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 .,?!"
```

so `ord("b")` would be `1` and `ord("c")` would be `2` ect.
How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Don't override a builtin -- That's just asking for someone else who works on your code (or your future self) to come looking for you to tell you it was a bad idea.  Instead, just write another function that does what you want it to and use that function.

Comment: Have you tried subtracting 97?

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

You're going about this the wrong way: you're making the mistake

> This existing thing doesn't meet my needs. I want to make it meet my needs!

instead, the way to go about the problem is

> This existing thing doesn't meet my needs. I need a thing that does meet my needs!

Once you realize that, the problem is now pretty straightforward. e.g.

```
DEFAULT_ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 .,?!"
def myord(x, alphabet=DEFAULT_ALPHABET):
    return alphabet.find(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
def my_ord(c):
  alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 .,?!"
  return alphabet.index(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `dict` to map from characters to indices and then do lookups into that. This will avoid repeatedly searching the string as other answers are suggesting (which is `O(n)`) and instead give `O(1)` lookup time with respect to the alphabet:

```
my_ord_dict = {c : i for i, c in enumerate(alphabet)}
my_ord_dict['0'] # 26
```

At that point you can easily wrap it in a function:

```
def my_ord(c):
    return my_ord_dict['0']
```

Or use the bound method directly

```
my_ord = my_ord_dict.__getitem__
```

But you don't want to change the name that refers to a builtin function, that'll confuse everyone else trying to use it that can see your change. If you are really trying to hurt yourself you can replace `my_ord` with `ord` in the above.

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood correctly, this is what you want:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 .,?!"

def crypt(c, key=97):
    return ord(c)-key

def decrypt(c, key=97):
    return chr(c+key)

dst = [crypt(c) for c in alphabet]
src = [decrypt(c) for c in dst]
print dst
print ''.join(src)
```